# Where Clause not working for Condition

Tags: mysql, where-clause, clause

$sql="SELECT * Year FROM sslc" Works Fine but when Condition is given its not working

$sql="SELECT Candidate, Father, Course, Year FROM sslc where Candidate LIKE '$Candidate' OR Father LIKE '$Father'";

2nd Code is working in localhost but when uploaded to server it says no data found

Answer (score 0):

While using `LIKE` operator, you need to make sure you wrap the value with wildcard (`%`) while querying, e.g.:

```
$sql="SELECT Candidate, Father, Course, Year FROM sslc where Candidate LIKE '%$Candidate%' OR Father LIKE '%$Father%'";
```

Comment: BIG BIG Thanks Darshan Mehta you saved my time. Its working Now.